# Which rockets use(d) solid-fuel upper stages?

Tags: solid-fuel, antares

The [Antares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antares_(rocket)) is unusual in that it's using solid-fuel in the second stage. I was surprised about that and a couple of questions immediately popped up which are already covered on this site: [How can a solid-fuel stage control thrust](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3339/how-do-you-handle-variations-in-launches-with-a-solid-second-stage) and [what are the advantages of using a solid-fuel upper-stage](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24167/advantages-of-a-solid-fueled-upper-stage) (no answers to that question at the time of this writing).

Since using a solid-fuel upper stage is unusual in a rocket that can achieve orbit, I was wondering whether there are other rockets besides the Antares that have used or are using this design?

Comment: Do all-solid designs like [Shavit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavit) count?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Yes since it's capable of reaching orbit and the upper stages use solid-fuels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this is going to be a list-based answer

- [Antares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antares_(rocket)) family (2013-) uses a [Castor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castor_(rocket_stage)) second stage
- [Black Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Arrow) (1969-1971) used a [waxwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waxwing_(rocket_motor)) third stage
- [Space Shuttle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle) (1981-2011) has used  [Inertial Upper Stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_Upper_Stage) and [Payload Assist Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_Assist_Module)
- [Titan 34D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_34D) (1982-1989) has used an [Inertial Upper Stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_Upper_Stage)
- [Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(rocket)) has used the [Star 27](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(rocket_stage)#Star_27)
- [Thor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGM-17_Thor) and [Minotaur V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minotaur_V) have used the [Star 37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor-Burner)
- [Delta II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_II), [Delta IV Heavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_IV_Heavy) and [Minotaur IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minotaur_IV) have used the [Star 48/(B)V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(rocket_stage)#Star_48)
- [Jupiter-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter-C) / [Juno-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juno_I) had two solid upper stages
- [Scout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scout_(rocket_family)), first orbital launch 1961 Feb. 16: four stages, all solids
- [Epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_(rocket)) (2014-) uses the M-35 second stage and KM-V2c third stage (with an optional hydrazine fourth stage) (the first three stages are all [HTPB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxyl-terminated_polybutadiene)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_solid-fuelled_orbital_launch_systems might be useful as source material.

Comment: Do kick stages really count?  In principle any payload could use a solid kick stage.  Main stages, like 2nd stage seem more relevant. However third stages get murky.

Comment: “Kick stage” is technically meaningless.